# Most efficient way to search for array in array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, search

I've got an large array `array1` filled with arrays of numbers already sorted like in the example below. Now I want to check, if the `array1` contains the `array2`.

Currently I've got the function `searchForArray` which works fine. But as I've got very large arrays for `array1`, it's very slow.

How can I improve my search function for better performance?

```
var array1 = [
    [1, 0], [1, 2], [1, 5], [1 , 12],
    [2, 3], [2, 9], [2, 25],
    [7, 2], [7, 4], [7, 7], [7, 8], [7, 16],
    [8, 20], [8, 35], [8, 40], [8, 50]
];
var array2 = [7, 4];

if (searchForArray(array1, array2)) {
    // Array 2 is in array1
}


function searchForArray(bigArray, searchArray) {
    const a = JSON.stringify(bigArray);
    const b = JSON.stringify(searchArray);
    const c = a.indexOf(b);
    if (c != -1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: does your `array1` always have that sorted nature? the 1st element of the inner arrays seem to be sorted, you could always use that for a binary search.

Comment: this question has a better place in : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if in case it gets downvoted by the community here

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar yes it's always sorted like that in nature. I'll try to implement a binary search to test how the performance increases.

Comment: its depends on your size of data, your constraints of time complexity and space complexity. With the small data sample like this, linear search is prefered, because you  don't have to go extra miles to sort it. FYI: there also are  `TreeMap` and `HashMap`

Comment: @HoangLe I've got very large arrays with size up to 20'000 elements. The data in the array are already automatically sorted as shown above so I don't have to implement a sort algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everybody who replied or gave some suggestions.

I now implemented a `binary search` algorithm, which speeds up my performance by far (process which took 110 sec are now executed in <1 sec).

Maybe there's someone who needs something similar:

```
function searchForArray(bigArray, searchArray) {
    var startIndex = 0;
    var endIndex = bigArray.length - 1;
    var startSearchIndex;
    var endSearchIndex;
    var firstIndexFound = false;

    while (startIndex <= endIndex) {
        var middle = Math.floor((startIndex + endIndex) / 2);

        if (bigArray[middle][0] === searchArray[0]) {
            // found the first key
            startIndex = middle;
            endIndex = middle;
            firstIndexFound = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (bigArray[middle][0] < searchArray[0]) {
            // continue searching to the right
            startIndex = middle + 1;
        }
        else {
            // search searching to the left
            endIndex = middle - 1;
        }
    }

    // Get index where to search for second key
    while (startIndex != 0 && bigArray[startIndex - 1][0] === searchArray[0]) {
        startIndex -= 1;
    }
    while (endIndex != bigArray.length - 1 && bigArray[endIndex + 1][0] === searchArray[0]) {
        endIndex += 1;
    }


    while (startIndex <= endIndex) {
        var middle = Math.floor((startIndex + endIndex) / 2);

        if (bigArray[middle][1] === searchArray[1]) {
            // found the second key
            return true;
        }
        else if (bigArray[middle][1] < searchArray[1]) {
            // continue searching to the right
            startIndex = middle + 1;
        }
        else {
            // search searching to the left
            endIndex = middle - 1;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: i would strongly recommend to use `let` and `const` instead of `var`. This will make sure that the variables remain in the scope and don't fiddle with the rest of the code.

Comment: also super glad to see something taking 110s being decreased to <1s 

Comment: Thanks for your input, as I didn't work that much with javascript until now I usually declare everything with `var`. I'll check out `let` and `const` for the future :)

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little more performant, because you don't need to JSON.stringify a huge array of arrays. Just look for the first item that has the same elements as the array you're looking for.

```
function searchForArray(bigArray, searchArray) {
    return !!bigArray.find(item => item.join(',') === searchArray.join(','));
}
```

Of course the speed of this depends on where `searchArray` exists in `bigArray`. If it's at the top, this is very fast. If in the bottom or does not exist at all, this will still take some time if `searchArray` is really huge. But at least this won't hog all your memory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this doesn't increase my performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try check without *JSON.stringify()*:

```js
function arraysEqual(a, b) {
    return a[0] === b[0] && a[1] === b[1]
}

function searchForArray(bigArray, searchArray) {
    return bigArray.some(a => arraysEqual(a, searchArray))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and let you know if it's faster

Comment: @StephanHäberle, I changed answer, for my tests it faster

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively convert your array of arrays into a hash table (implementation is up to you). Here is one such example:

We will compute the key for each element by summing up the values in the array and keep an array of arrays for the resulting values (since we can have more than one element with the same sum)

```
var array1 = {
    1: [[1, 0]],
    3: [[1, 2]],
    5: [[2, 3]],
    6: [[1, 5]],
    9: [[7, 2]],
    11: [[1, 12], [2, 9], [7, 4]],
    14: [[7, 7]],
    15: [[7, 8]],
    23: [[7, 16]],
    27: [[2, 25]],
    28: [[8, 20]],
    43: [[8, 35]],
    48: [[8, 40]],
    58: [[8, 50]]
}
```

This allows us to determine if some other element is present in the list in O(1) time on average.

```
const a = [2, 9]

const s = a.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0)

const v = map[s]

for (let i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
    if (JSON.stringify(v[i]) == JSON.stringify(a)) {
        console.log(true)
        return;d
    }
}

console.log(false)
```

Note that this is only practical when the list is known ahead of time, otherwise it will take O(n) just to construct the hash table